# How to insert date in a table with a different format?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, asp-classic

My problem here is that I have a date value as `05/09/2013`  in a HTML text box which cannot be altered.

Now sql only accepts date format as `yyyy/mm/dd`. so while inserting this textbox value into sql database it does not support this format and throws an exception.

Therefore my question is how to insert a textbox value with different format into a sql database?

For instance my code would look like

```
insert into table (date) value('"& date& "')
```

input box has a calender type textbox and sends a date in  `05/09/2013` format

Comment: How are you trying to insert the date value?  Using ADO .NET or something else?  If you tell SQL Server that the value is a date it will respect the actual value.

Comment: yes. using ADODB.connect. I am making this application in Classic ASP and used ADo connection.. not the text box is a auto generated field - using ajax calender. the data format is different in the text box .. how to tell sql server that the value is date..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

For MySQL use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (date)
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('05/09/2013', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ae1f/2)**

Based on your comments the query should look like

```
sql = "INSERT INTO shiftpatterns (siteNumber,shiftdate) SELECT '"&siteNumber&"', 'STR_TO_DATE('"&shiftdate&"','%d/%m/%Y')"
```

**Original answer**

For SQL Server use [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ([date])
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '05/09/2013', 103)
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c3bc/1)**

In both cases

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

will give you:

```
|                             DATE |
------------------------------------
| September, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Comment: is this right ... what do I need to change here.. because i cannot upload anythng onto the database:

"sql = "INSERT INTO  shiftpatterns (siteNumber,shiftdate) values('"&siteNumber &"', 'STR_TO_DATE('"&shiftdate&"','%Y,%m,%d')')""

please help me

Comment: @snowman See updated answer. First of all, to be able to use a function you need to utilize `INSERT ... SELECT` instead of `INSERT ... VALUES`. And secondly you need to use correct format string `'%d/%m/%Y'` instead of `'%Y,%m,%d'`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your tags you're using classic ASP, so we can assume that you're using a `form` to submit the data to the ASP page you're writing.

The most fault-tolerant way, if you cannot edit the client-side page, is to spool up a date object, parse the supplied value, and then extract your data from there.  Or, you could just treat it as a string, test for the expected format, and then maniplate the string into the clearer form.

```
function fixDate(inStr)
  if inStr like '99/99/9999' then
    fixDate = LEFT(inStr,4) + "/" + RIGHT(inStr,4)
  endif
end function
```

Comment: how and where to use this function ?

Comment: You would use that, or a line similar to it, in the ASP portion of your code that retrieves the _GET or _POST variables from the request and builds the SQL statement to run against your database.  (It's been years since I've even looked at classic ASP, so it may not have VB6's `like` syntax.)

Comment: I totally dont understand how to use function... well i have a form which sends this textfile as a string and string value is 06/09/1989 .. now when I use request.form("date") it returns the same string. after that i have used the sql insert statement. as above. this format is not supported by the sql server so it returns null value.. all I want to do is make it right while inserting into the database.